# IIS SQL Server credentials

Tags: iis, sql-server-2008-r2, credentials

I have added a website to IIS, and I have set networkuser and the IIS user to the property but when I try browsing the site every static page is opening normally but every dynamic page is not.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have created a username and password to connect from my application to the database, when I run the website from Visual Studio it works perfectly but from IIS it doesn't. What should I do?

I have tryed the sa user in SQL Server but it didnt work.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? And which version of IIS?

Comment: iis 7, it is always returning null from the db

Comment: Have you tried it with a simple query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM someTable`? Is there something in your query which is environment-dependent?